# Applying gravity to a 2D array in XNA game

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

I am working on a game somewhat similar to Tetris. I have arrived at a roadblock when it comes to handling the gravity logic. (I'm working in XNA if it's at all relevant)

Without wasting your time by going into details I essentially have a 2D array. There are 4 types of pieces: empty(0), blue(1), green(2), red(3) and yellow(4).

In this game it will be possible to form NxM solid blocks of the same color. This is the part which makes the logic messy. I hope it doesn't sound too vague for now but I will show an example and show my progress so far.

```
    int[,] example = new int[5,5]
        {
            { 0,0,1,0,4 },
            { 0,2,2,0,0 },
            { 0,2,2,2,0 },
            { 0,0,0,3,0 },
            { 1,2,2,0,0 }

        };
```

Let's say that this is the board state right now. As you can see there is a 2x2 of 2's(greens) and some pieces floating in mid-air. My plan is to play an animation of those pieces falling down until the place underneath is occupied, update all solids. I was trying to fix this and it worked fine if I was just looking at gravity for single 1x1 pieces. When it came to handling 2x2's and bigger blocks it became a big mess and I just got stuck.

My attempt at this was to have a List to keep track of all blocks that are on the gameboard, this would be updated every time the gravity update method was called.

```
            int[,] board = new int[6, 6];
            bool[,] isBlock = new bool[board.GetLength(0), board.GetLength(1)];
            List<int[]> blocks = new List<int[]>();
            List<int[]> toplayAnimation = new List<int[]>();


            for (int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(1) - 1; y++)
                {
                    if ((isBlock[x, y] == false) && (board[x, y + 1] == 0) && (board[x, y] != 0))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

If we look at the example the result should be that the board is updated and an animation is played of the pieces falling down it should look like this:

```
int[,] example = new int[5,5]
        {
            { 0,0,0,0,0 },
            { 0,0,1,0,0 },
            { 0,2,2,0,0 },
            { 0,2,2,2,0 },
            { 1,2,2,3,4 }

        };
```

So I basically have the question, what approach do you suggest I take when tackling this problem? I was thinking of having two separate 2D arrays for blocks and single pieces and comparing them two in the loop. I have been stuck on this for a little over two weeks now and I couldn't seem to find any help in already existing threads. Hope I explained everything well, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a block class and a List<Block> to keep track of all the properties.  The block class will contain the size of the block, where it is located on the board, orientation, color.

Comment: By curiousity, did you look to this http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/ ?
Have a look to the source code :)

I think you already found this thread that may or may not help you: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-are-some-known-2d-3d-physics-engines-for-xna

Comment: jdweng, Thank you. I didn't think of that for some reason!
pix, Thank you. I will check out the farseer physics link. It looks like I could use it instead of writing all the code myself :)

Comment: Do you want me to add this an answer to your question? :) 
edit: I just did it as an answer :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look here:

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/
Like this you will not have the pain to rebuild an entire engine from scratch :)

There lot more:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-are-some-known-2d-3d-physics-engines-for-xna